# Update customize after change

Tags: customize

It seems that once customizable variables are loaded, the Customize interface is not updated on subsequent re-evaluation of those variables, even with `eval-defun` (`C-M-x`).

For example, adding a `:prefix` to a `defgroup` and `C-M-x`ing does not update the names of customizable variables in that group in the Customize interface.

Why is this happening, and what can be done to "force update" Customize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're saying. Keyword `:prefix` does not change the names of variables that are in the group. It does not affect the variable names. All it does is declare that the group uses that prefix.

And if option `custom-unlispify-remove-prefixes` is non-`nil` then variable names are shown in Customize buffers without their prefix.

Is that what you are trying to describe: that you expect to see the names without prefixes but you see the prefixes (in Customize buffers)? If so, is that option non-`nil`?

If a Customize buffer already exists showing a variable then it does not get updated to reflect a change in that option value. But if you kill that Customize buffer and re-create it then you should see the option value being respected.

If this does not answer your question, please try to clarify what you mean: what you see and what you expected to see instead. Consider providing a recipe.

See the Elisp manual, node [Group Definitions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Group-Definitions.html) for the description of `defgroup` keyword `:prefix`.

Comment: OK, I had 2 issues. One was that `custom-unlispify-remove-prefixes` was `nil`. The other was that I didn't kill the existing Customize buffers, and therefore changes weren't being reflected.

Comment: I see that @phils has just now filed Emacs enhancement request (bug) #[26871](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26871) asking to be able to revert a Customize buffer, i.e., not have to kill it and re-create it. Thanks, Phil!